# iCloud Integration in IOS app

Tags: ios7, contacts, icloud, abaddressbook

I am working on iOS app for managing contacts. I want to add features to access contacts from iCloud and also store my current contacts of my app to iCloud? Is that possible? Any help will be appreciated.